# Why do different instances of the same program use up different amounts of memory?

Tags: memory, ram

I simply started 5 instances of the default xterm, doing nothing in them at all.

Looking at the output from htop, it appears that these instances use different amounts of RAM:

```
VIRT        RES       SHR       Command
12632       8528      4916       xterm
12632       8528      4920       xterm
12616       8496      4900       xterm
12616       8464      4868       xterm
12616       8452      4856       xterm
```

I know the differences are slight, but it does peak my curiosity.  Google was unhelpful.  Does anyone know why there are these small differences?

Answer (score 1):

Most programs allocate memory as needed during their execution (asking for more memory from the operating system). They rarely give back memory (most of the time, after running a while the memory will be a mosaic of used and currently free pieces of different sizes, compacting that to free a contiguous are that can be returned is extra work, rarely worth it). Thus different memory usage.